# How to build the modal in my case

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am using a bootstrap `modal` for my app. I have bunch of element inside my `modal`.

However, one of my element inside the `modal` is set as `absolute` position and the element is bigger than the modal. I want to show the element on top of the `modal` instead of being cut off inside the `modal`. I have tried the `z-index` but it doesn't work. Any suggestion? Thanks a lot!

modal html

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                Test
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
               //....contents..
               <div class="option"> lots of stuff...</div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.option{
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 600px;
}
```

It shows like

```
 --------------
|              |
|       -------|
|      |option |
|       -------|
|
```

but I want

```
 --------------
|              |
|       --------------
|      |   option     |
|       --------------
|              |
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, the modal has "overflow:hidden". This property is causing large inner elements to cut off, instead of extending outside the bounds of the parent element.
You can override bootstrap's style and use "overflow:visible", but this may have other negative side effects on the style.

Comment: I have tried to change overflow to visible but still no luck. +1

Comment: I'm going off the example in the bootstrap docs. 

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals  

Upon inspecting the modal, I see that the .modal class has "overflow:hidden" as well as "overflow-x:hidden" and "overflow-y:auto". 

According to your diagram, the elements are being cut off along the overflow-x. Please try "overflow-x:visible" and even declare "!important" if it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

**CSS:**

```
.option{
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 600px;
}
```

it will work please check it .

Comment: if its work for you please tick the answer so that others can also use it. @FlyingCat